# bar construction for algebras with unusual grading of d

Tags: differential-graded-algebras, reference-request

The bar construction is usually applied to differential graded algebras with differential $d$ of degree +1 or -1. Using multiple (de)suspensions, it also works for $d$ of any degree $\neq 0$. Is this fact mentioned in the literature, or is it folklore? -- Jim Stasheff

Comment: I meant to ask for a reference
Don't know why I'm listed as unknown??

jim stasheff

Comment: Jim, I edited your question to make it clearer what the question is. If I got it wrong, there's an edit button. (Did you sign in on an unregistered account?  You can request an account merger over at meta.) 